# Serverless AWS: extend permissions of default IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Using the `serverless.yml` configuration file, I'm trying to extend the permissions of the default lambda IAM role to allow my lambda to send SQS messages to a SQS that was previously created, but I can't manage to make it work.

In my `serverless.yml` file, I have the following `provider` settings:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  region: eu-central-1
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - sqs:SendMessage
            - sqs:GetQueueUrl
            - sqs:GetQueueAttributes
          Resource:
            Fn::Join:
              - ':'
              - - 'arn:aws:sqs'
                - Ref: AWS::Region
                - Ref: AWS::AccountId
                - test-output-sqs
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/), this additional statement should be merged into the generated policy.
However, it is not. I am missing something ?

Comment: Your code works for me with Serverless 2.28.7 - which version of Serverless do you use? Check with `serverless -v`.

Comment: might be worthwhile to check the IAM Role statement via the console to see if the role permissions are correct. On the Console you see that your Lambda function has access the Que.

Comment: you're right ! it seems my version of serverless was a bit too old. seems to work fine with v2.29. Thanks a lot!